# Why can't I deploy a Process Builder referencing a Custom Metadata in a Formula?

Tags: process-builder, deployment, metadata-api, ant

I created a Process Builder in which I reference a Custom Metadata from a Formula inside of the "Update Record" action. It works fine on a Environment 1, but I have trouble with deploying it to another Env using Ant. I receive the following error:

```
All Component Failures:
1.  flows/Assign_Consulting_Request.flow -- Error: formula_12_myRule_11_A1_9453158556 (Formula) - The formula expression is invalid: Field ROW does not exist. Check spelling.
```

I'm a bit surprised because I don't have any `ROW` field. It's a record and the XML code for PB's formula is here:

```
<formulas>
    <processMetadataValues>
        <name>originalFormula</name>
        <value>
            <stringValue>$CustomMetadata.ConsultingServiceOwnerSettings__mdt.ROW.DefaultConsultingOpsOwnerId__c</stringValue>
        </value>
    </processMetadataValues>
    <name>formula_12_myRule_11_A1_9453158556</name>
    <dataType>String</dataType>
    <expression>{!$CustomMetadata.ConsultingServiceOwnerSettings__mdt.ROW.DefaultConsultingOpsOwnerId__c}</expression>
</formulas>
```

`package.xml` file provided below. As you can see I included the `ROW` record. I don't receive any errors on retrieve so I suppose everything should be fine here.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>ConsultingServiceOwnerSettings__mdt.APAC</members>
        <members>ConsultingServiceOwnerSettings__mdt.NA</members>
        <members>ConsultingServiceOwnerSettings__mdt.ROW</members>
        <name>CustomMetadata</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>ConsultingServiceOwnerSettings__mdt</members>
        <name>CustomObject</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>Assign_Consulting_Request</members>
        <name>Flow</name>
    </types>
    <version>46.0</version>
</Package>
```

In addition to that - the record is in retrieved package directory.

[image]

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is in your package.xml. When you reference the **Custom Metadata type** in **Custom object**, you utilize *__mdt*

However, when you reference **records** of a Custom Metadata Type, you **do not include** *__mdt*.

This is mentioned in the Metadata API documentation for [Custom Metadata](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_custommetadata.htm)

[image]

If you change your package.xml to this, it should appropriately bring the records over.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>ConsultingServiceOwnerSettings.APAC</members>
        <members>ConsultingServiceOwnerSettings.NA</members>
        <members>ConsultingServiceOwnerSettings.ROW</members>
        <name>CustomMetadata</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>ConsultingServiceOwnerSettings__mdt</members>
        <name>CustomObject</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>Assign_Consulting_Request</members>
        <name>Flow</name>
    </types>
    <version>46.0</version>
</Package>
```

Comment: Thanks so much Kris, that was the issue! I just don't get it - if that's the proper way of using ``CustomMetadata`` component - why did Ant manage to retrieve the records at all?

Comment: That's a good question that I don't have an answer for! I'd check by opening the record file (.md) to see if it's got the same info as it does when you use the correct package.xml.

Comment: It's the same  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯